# Subir una imagen en Django mediante una dirección web

Tags: django

Verán, quiero crear una base de datos de personas, la cual tiene una variable de foto, pero el formulario con la información de la persona no cojera la foto del pc del usuario, sino de una URL en internet.

Este es el modelo:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    foto = models.FileField(upload_to='', unique=True)
    nacimiento = models.DateField()

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'persona'
        ordering = ['apellidos']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre+" "+self.apellidos
```

Este es el formulario:

```
<form class="mb-5" action="{% url 'people-save' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" value="{{ persona.id }}">
    <p>Nombre: <input required class="form-control" type="text" value="{{persona.nombre}}" name="nombre"></p>
    <p>Apellidos: <input required class="form-control" type="text" value="{{persona.apellidos}}" name="apellidos"></p>
    <p>Fecha de nacimiento: <input required class="form-control" type="date" value="{{fecha | date:'Y-m-d'}}" name="nacimiento"></p>
    <p><b><i><u>Adjunta la foto mediante una URL:</u></i></b>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="image_url" name="image_url"
               placeholder="Pega la url de la foto." value="{{ ImgUrlForm.image_url }}"></p>
    <div class="mb-3 d-grid gap-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Y esta es la vista que crea al usuario:

```
def guardar_persona(request):
    modificacion = request.POST.get("id")
    ruta = request.POST.get('image_url')
    if ruta != '':
        foto = ruta
    else:
        foto = request.FILES.get("foto")
    fecha = request.POST.get("nacimiento")
    if fecha == "":
        fecha = date.today()
    if modificacion:
        codigo = int(request.POST.get("id"))
        persona = Persona.objects.get(id=codigo)
        persona.nombre = request.POST.get("nombre")
        persona.apellidos = request.POST.get("apellidos")
        # Si modificas una persona, puedes dejar la variable de la foto en blanco para no sustituirla.
        if foto:
            try:
                os.remove(persona.foto.path)
            except:
                print("Foto inexistente")
            finally:
                if ruta != '':
                    url_web(ruta)
                    persona.foto = myimage
                else:
                    persona.foto = foto
        persona.nacimiento = fecha
        persona.save()
    else:
        if ruta != '':
            url_web(ruta)
            foto = myimage
        persona = Persona.objects.create(
            nombre=request.POST.get("nombre"),
            apellidos=request.POST.get("apellidos"),
            foto=foto,
            nacimiento=fecha
        )
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/cine/filtrar_persona/{}/".format(persona.id))
```

Esta vista utiliza la función "url_web", la cual tiene este código:

```
def url_web(url):
    global myimage
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    cadena = parsed.path
    posicion_barra = cadena.rfind('/')
    myimage = cadena[posicion_barra + 1:]
    img.save(os.getcwd() + '/static/img/' + myimage)
```

Y me da este formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La foto se debe guardar en un fichero llamado "C:\Users\Pcx\PycharmProjects\python_g2\static\img", pero cuando ejecuto el programa, me topo con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontre como resolverlo.
Estoy utilizando Pycharm, donde se puede configurar para ejecutar el proyecto pulsando el botón de Iniciar Programa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me olvide de indicar en que directorio se trabajo, lo cual confundia a os.getcwd(). Una vez lo añadí, se soluciono.